# Openssl base64 decoded string does not always decrypt

Tags: c, windows, openssl

I am trying to encrypt some plain text with a public key using RSA_public_encrypt(), this data would then be sent to a remote server for validation. I believe I have the encryption/decryption working, since the output of RSA_public_encrypt can be passed to RSA_private_decrypt and it works. The problem I am having now is I need to base64 encode the data in order to send it over HTTP.

As a test (before sending it to the server) I am encoding to base64 the output of RSA_public_encrypt(), then decoding it and passing it back into RSA_private_decrypt(). This appears to work some of the time, and fails with an error like this:

```
error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error
```

When I use memcmp to compare the original data (pre-base64) to the output of my base64 decode function I receive a -1 despite the contents appearing to match (in Visual Studio by viewing the contents of the memory as hex). I have also checked the base64 encoded version with various online tools and they appear to decode to the expected value.

I have double checked that the input/output from the base64/unbase64 functions are null terminated which appears to make little difference.

I've been going round in circles with this problem for a couple of days but I believe it must be something with the base64 encode/decode process because when that is not involved everything works. If anyone has any advice on how this could be happening it would be appreciated.

**Openssl version:** 1.0.1c

**Platform:** Windows/MSVC

**Base64 Code:**

```
char *base64(const unsigned char *input, int length)
{
  BIO *bmem, *b64;
  BUF_MEM *bptr;
  char *buff = NULL;

  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
  bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
  BIO_write(b64, input, length);
  BIO_flush(b64);
  BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);

  buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length+1);
  memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length);
  buff[bptr->length] = '\0';

  BIO_free_all(b64);

  return buff;
}
```

**Unbase64 Code:**

```
char *unbase64(unsigned char *input, int length)
{
  BIO *b64, *bmem;

  char *buffer = (char *)malloc(length+1);
  memset(buffer, 0, length+1);

  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
  bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf(input, length);
  bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

  BIO_read(bmem, buffer, length);
  buffer[length] = '\0';

  BIO_free_all(bmem);

  return buffer;
}
```

**Encrypted "hello world" example:**

```
š:Œ¼JŒ"ÌïëŸÔè#¢Oo‚À–    œê\çrú¿±a/8ƒòÌ¢Q\T¹]nío
```

**Base64 version (using the above code):**

```
G5qdOgWMvEqMIswZ7+uf1OgPI6JPb4LAlgmc6lzncvq/sWEvOIPyzByiUVwMjYFUuV0Vbu1v
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the correct size in the `unbase64` function? It should be the size of the base64 buffer returned, not the size of the destination buffer i.e. using an example main function:

```
int main(void)
{
  unsigned char bufron[2000];
  int i;
  char *chab;
  unsigned char *chac;

  for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
      bufron[i] = i % 255;
  }

  chab = base64(bufron, 2000);
  printf("%s\n", chab);

  chac = unbase64(chab, strlen(chab));

  for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
      if (bufron[i] != chac[i]) {
          printf("Failed at %d\n", i);
          return (1);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The size being passed into `unbase64` was correct, however your answer got me checking all the sizes. Turns out I wasn't using the correct length when calling `base64()`. I was using `base64(str, strlen(str))`, but the binary string must of contained a NULL. Changing it to `base64(str, 256)` fixed the problem. (where 256 is the size of the string as reported by openssl). Thanks!